# Will creating an obligation come under state?

Tags: corda, states

I want to create an obligation stating all the details about a particular property which is to be transferred to another party. So is creating this obligation a state?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Because if not, then you shouldn't ask it on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In Corda any shared fact on the ledger is a state.

In general, CorDapps decompose into three main parts:

- States, which describe shared facts
- Contracts, which govern the evolution of these shared facts
- Flows, which allow your node to execute some process, generally related to updating the ledger's shared facts